# Puzzler on construction of a 2-stock portfolio

Tags: equities, correlation, hedging

Lets say you get to choose any 2 stocks.

Is it *possible* that a portfolio can be built from the two stocks (long or short either, any weighting) that has a lower volatility (standard deviation of movements), and simultaneously higher percent return than either of the two underlying securities alone.

I want to say yes, but I think the answer is no.
In the event of a correlation of -1 between A and B:

**A:** a stock with high stddev, and small positive return

**B:** a stock with same stddev, and small negative return

**Long A short B** = much higher returns, much higher stddev

**Short A Long B** = 0 return, 0 stddev

I currently have an infinite loop randomly building portfolios to test this at home. Bonus: Is it possible with a portfolio with more than 2 stocks in the portfolio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ perfectly correlated with same vol.
So $X-Y$ has no volatility at all and for any $n$, $n(X-Y)$ has still no volatility.

If $r_X > r_Y$ are returns of $X$ and $Y$, then $n(X-Y)$ has return $n(r_X-r_Y)$ which can be as big as you want with $n$ big enough.

Comment: Something like this can happen accidentally in a large problem if your input data is crappy, and that is one reason why people sometimes put in a long only constraint before running the optimization.

Comment: Sorry, I do not fully understand your solution. Are you making assumptions about the securities? n appears to be a multiplier here, which is not relevant to the problem. if it is a weight it should be (n)(x)-(1-n)(y).

Comment: Let A and B have same variance, correlation 0.9999. Return of A 10% a year, B 5% a year. Then for example let w1=1001 and w2=−1000. Then w1+w2=1 and you make approx 1000 times the difference in return between the two securities i.e. 50% a year.

Comment: Understood, so the return can easily be higher, and as long as (A-B) has lower volatility then either A or B then the second condition is fulfilled, implying that it is possible. Thanks!